# Geodesics on a cylinder: straight line or helix?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

It is known that geodesics on a cylinder are helical lines (helix). As a special case of a helix--- straight line. But one can take two points so cleverly that you can draw two helixes between them (see picture), one of which is a straight line. Both satisfy geodesics differential equation. The question: is, can they both be considered as geodesics or only the shortest one is "true" geodesic?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what you define a geodesic. Usually, a geodesic is a parametrized curve that locally minimizes the distance between points. A geodesic segment is a geodesic that realises the distance between its endpoints. With this convention, your two lines are geodesics, while only the blue one is a geodesic segment.

Comment: A geodesic is *not* defined as the shortest path between two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only reasonable definition of a geodesic in such situations involves *locally* optimal (shorter) paths.  After all, consider the case where the two end points are on precisely opposite positions on the cylinder.  There are two equivalent arcs (geodesics).  (There are an infinite number of geodesics on a sphere linking anti-podes, such as the north and south poles.)  For a cylinder there are, then, an infinite number of geodesics in the arbitrary case, indexed by the number of rotations of the helix around the cylinder (like a winding number).

"[A geodesic is a locally length-minimizing curve.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Geodesic.html)"

[image]

Comment: That is, we can say that two geodesics pass through the points A and B. Right?

Comment: "A geodesic is a locally length-minimizing curve."  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Geodesic.html

Comment: Ok then how can I name the curves going through points A and B and that satisfy the geodesic equations? They both geodesics, I think, because they both a locally length-minimizing curves. Am I right?

Comment: Yep............

Comment: Thank you, "Yep" quite enough for completeness! I really wanted to read it:)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of rotations executed between the end points  $(A,B)$ we have an infinite number of local length minimizing geodesics as helices shown on their cylindrical development.

There is one shortest among them running vertically down that you have sketched.

In development all helices are straight lines.

They are inclined to the generator line $L$ as

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{n\cdot 2 \pi R}{L}$$

whose periodicity can be visualized as below for $n=0,1,2,3$ in a development of multiple winding numbers associated with periodic wraps.

[image]

Comment: Is any good picture for deminstraing locally length minimisation procedure which is give us curve?Because, I think this picture https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikiversity/en/5/5d/TrialFunction.png show somesing different then local minimisation procedure

Comment: Sounds like minimization with a constraint that still needs a definition...